# Overlapping DIVs despite trying to use clear

Tags: html, css, overlapping

i am trying to create a page which has a left column containing 5 blocks, a right column containing 5 blocks and a central column as just one big block. It displays OK on a desktop but on a mobile device it does not. The right blocks overlap the main central block.

i am just starting out with this so apologies any stupid questions.

I have tried a variety of combinations of clearing floats and changing the floats in an attempt to try and fix this but it just wont behave as i want it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Mario

```
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
      width:100%;
      color:#000000;
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
      background-image:url('Background Image');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    a  { color:#602e91; }
    a:visited { color:#800080; }
    a:hover { color:#008000; }
    a:active { color:#FF0000; }

#blocks {
    width:90%
    margin:auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#MainLeftBlock1 {
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    float: left;
}
#LBlock1 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
#LBlock2 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
#LBlock3 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
#LBlock4 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
#LBlock5 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}

#MainCentreBlock {
    height:100%;
    width:60%;
float:left;
}
#MainRightBlock3 {
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
float:right;
}
#RBlock4 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: right;
}
#Rblock5 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: right;
}
#Rblock6 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: right;
}
#Rblock7 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: right;
}
#Rblock8 {
    height:20%;
    width:100%;
    float: right;
}
    -->
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="blocks">
    <div id="MainLeftBlock1">
    <div align="middle" id="LBlock1"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/mcdonaldslogo.jpg" width="100%" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="LBlock2"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/faroukstandoorilogo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="LBlock3"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/donellislogo.jpg" width="100%" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="LBlock4"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/hogstoplogo.jpg" width="120" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="LBlock5"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/paradiselogo.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <div align="middle" id="MainCentreBlock"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/lufffoodlogo2.jpg" width="750" height="494" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>

    <div id="MainRightBlock3">
    <div align="middle" id="RBlock4"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/kfclogo.jpg" width="100%" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="Rblock5"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/planburritologo.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="Rblock6"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM LANDING PAGE"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/delhibiteslogo.jpg" width="100%" height="100" alt="" title="" align="middle" /></a></div>
    <div align="middle" id="Rblock7"></div>
    <div align="middle" id="Rblock8"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

     <div align="middle"><img src="http://www.lufffood.co.uk/img/AvailableNowHome.png" align="middle" /></div> 
 <div align="middle"><a href="mailto:info@lufffood.co.uk?subject=QUERY FROM     LANDING PAGE">Click Here To Email Us For More Info!</a></div>

      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make responsive design (mobile and desktop version). Use media query instead:

[css-trick](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have created code using the [flexbox method](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which I would recommend learning as it seems like you are a beginner. Here are some useful sites for web development:

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/)
[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
main{
  display: flex;
}
aside{
  flex:2;
}
aside div {
  background-color:white;
  margin: 10px;
}
section{
  flex:5;
}
section div {
  margin:10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside><!-- left -->
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div>Center</div>
  </section>
  <aside><!-- right -->
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </aside>
</main>
```